# Wrong location of marker when rendered in component

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-markers

I am trying to show some markers on Google Map using ReactJs.

For now I have two fixed locations (London and Paris), but later I want to load locations from server so I want them to be handled in separate component.

For some reason when I render Paris in separate component its put into the corner of the map. I can move the map around, zoom it, but Paris is still in the corner.

[image: london and paris markers]
[image: london and paris markers zoomed]

Here is my code:

```
var center = { lat: 49.1951, lng: 16.6068 };
var zoom = 3;

const K_WIDTH = 40;
const K_HEIGHT = 40;

const greatPlaceStyle = {
    // initially any map object has left top corner at lat lng coordinates
    // it's on you to set object origin to 0,0 coordinates
    position: 'absolute',
    width: K_WIDTH,
    height: K_HEIGHT,
    left: -K_WIDTH / 2,
    top: -K_HEIGHT / 2,

    border: '5px solid #f44336',
    borderRadius: K_HEIGHT,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#3f51b5',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    padding: 4
};

class PlaceMarkers extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div style={greatPlaceStyle} lat="48.8566" lng="2.3522">Paris</div>
        )
    }
}

class PlaceBlock extends React.Component{   

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="thumbnail ep-map">
                    <GoogleMap defaultCenter={center} defaultZoom={zoom}>
                    <div style={greatPlaceStyle} lat="51.5074" lng="0.1278">London</div>
                    <PlaceMarkers/>
                    </GoogleMap>
                </div>
            </div>
     )
}
```

I am very new to ReactJs so it might be something very simple?

Edit:

Thanks to [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7106958/max-vorobjev) I made a few changes. Now my markers work even when loaded from server (using axios for GET). Instead of having each marker as separate component I have renamed my component to GoogleMapBlock and let it handle the map including markers:

```
class GoogleMapBlock extends React.Component{   

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            markers: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
        .get(getBaseUrl()+`get`)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                markers: response.data.markers
            });
        })
        .catch((e) => 
        {
            console.error(e);
        });
    }

    render(){

        var myMarkers = [];
        var count = 1;
        this.state.markers.forEach(function(marker){
            var markerId = "markerId" + count;//marker.key
            myMarkers.push(
                <div id={markerId} style={greatPlaceStyle} lat={marker.position.lat} lng={marker.position.lng}>{marker.title}</div>
            );
            count++;
        });

        return(
                <div className="thumbnail ep-map">
                    <GoogleMap defaultCenter={center} defaultZoom={zoom}>
                    {myMarkers}
                    </GoogleMap>
                </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because GoogleMap component expects lat and lng props under it's child component. If you look in the react dev tool you will see that there are 2 components under google map:
 - div with lat and lng
 - PlaceMarkers without lat and lng (which have div with lat and lng)

You need to set lat and lng props for PlaceMarkers explicitly:

```
<GoogleMap defaultCenter={center} defaultZoom={zoom}>
  <div style={greatPlaceStyle} lat="51.5074" lng="0.1278">London</div>
  <PlaceMarkers lat="48.8566" lng="2.3522"/>
</GoogleMap>
```

React Component is a view, therefore it should not be used to store data (though it might still have view state), that's why we need props - to initialize component with the data. In your case I suggest to pick a storage framework, like Redux, and initialize components in runtime:

```
render() {
  let markers = this.state.markers.map(m => <PlaceMarkers {...m}/>);

  return <GoogleMap defaultCenter={center} defaultZoom={zoom}>
           {markers}
       </GoogleMap>
}
```

, where this.state.markers is Array like [{lat: "48.8566", lng: "2.3522", name: "London"}, ...]